I have several variables which sum to zero. Is it sensible to substitute each variable as the independent variable to get a better estimate of each
In economics there is an equation by Kalecki which sums over government expenditure, taxation, exports, imports, savings, consumption, investment, and profit to zero. The US NBER facilitates that with a statistical discrepancy. Other countries don't track it as closely, but researchers occasionally do. I want to determine how to spread the discrepancy. I thought to put each variable on the LHS in turn, then adjust each. What i want to know is if that is the best way to reduce the discrepancy, or else somehow determine what variables should get more or less allocated to them.
Any hints on a sound process to follow that stands up to criticism would be appreciated.

"The US NBER facilitates that with a statistical discrepancy" What is US NBER, and what does it mean that it 'facilitates that'? What do you mean by 'statistical discrepancy'?

"I thought to put each variable on the LHS in turn, then adjust each." I guess that LHS means left hand side (of some equation), but what is the point of doing that. The 'adjust each' what does that mean?

Do you mean, you have given estimates of some variables like expenditure, taxation, exports, imports, savings, consumption, investment, and profit. Those estimates have inaccuracies and the sum is not exactly zero. You want to use the model in which they sum up to zero, to improve the estimates?

This makes me think of How best to estimate regression parameters subject to constraints?. Depending on your goals you may not want to adjust the estimates. For example, if you compute total expenditure over ten years, then it is best to use the raw numbers rather than the adjusted numbers.

US NBER is USA National Bureu of Economic Research. The variables have names like  the ones shown eg exports, importes. The LHS means the independent variable that could be moved across replacing the zero. I mean there is data from 2023 back to 1960 for times series of hundreds of variables, of which i am interested in 8 or so. I will look into your reference.

statistical discrepancy means that they know the equation should balance, but because they use data which includes money from US citizens and corporations abroad in profit, it isn't the same as under GDP, so they expect it will differ from the true GDP component.

You could model the observations as a multivariate normal distribution (with zero correlation) and compute the maximum likelihood with the constraint that the sum is zero.
For this you can scale the variables such that the covariance matrix of the multivariate normal distribution becomes an identity matrix, then project linearly on the constraint (which has transformed as well).
Here is an example in 2D. You observed $(x,y) = (2.68,5.85)$ and correct it to be $(\hat{x},\hat{y}) =(3,3)$, according to a projection onto the constraint.
You do not do this directly with a perpendicular projection, which results in the red square mark at $(4.26,4.26)$ on the left image, but instead you consider an oval shape for the errors according to the standard deviations that are estimated (in this example debit has three times larger inaccuracy), and the perpendicular projection is made in a transformed space where the estimated standard deviations are equal.


That seems clever, not sure how it fits my case just yet, have to think on that. Did you see my clarification to Sextus Empericus?

I don't see how I can distribute the discrepancy to the individual variables because keeping the debits and credits separate, eg, exports and imports is important.  It may be necessary to include both GDP and GNP to get a separate take on discrepancy which is most likely related mainly to profit.  That is because firms can write off or write back book entries for depreciation retained earnings, share buy backs, mergers out of sync with trading surplus.

Unfortunately, i don't understand how to use your suggestion when i have several variables, which together experience an overall constraint. Do i need to reword my question?
